# What is the context of 5:64?

Tags: tafseer, judaism, surat-al-maidah

According to the Qur'an ([Surat al-Ma'idah 64](http://quran.com/5/64)),

> *The Jews say: "Allah's hand is tied up."*

My question is where did the Jews ever say such a thing? I mean if you were to ask a Jew whether Allah's hand is tied up - he would probably answer:

> *"Nay, both His hands are widely outstretched: He giveth and spendeth (of His bounty) as He pleaseth"*

so I wonder what it the subtext of this? What does this ayah really mean?

Answer (score 1):

The words used are "Al-Yahud" (The Jews) instead of just "Yahud" (Jews). If you were to start reading about 8-10 verses back and come to this, you would quite easily figure out that this is talking about some specific Jews who were opponents to the Prophet Muhammad(s). Those Jews must have then be saying what is said in this verse.

It is not a general statement since there are many other verses of the Quran that speak of praises for the Jews. Thus, in general, Muslims can have (and should have) cordial relationships with those around them regardless of their faith.

Comment: Please add some references to your answer. Try to practice How to answer.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, it'd be great if you can point me where I can find "How to answer", and I'll improve my response based on that. I originally thought that at least the references were sufficient (i.e. the word used in the verse in Q & reference to previous verses), but I am sure I missed something which led you to make this comment. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Brother, You may learn [how to write a good answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) if you practice it. Moreover [referencing](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) adds value to your answer. You'd better mention the verses you are talking about (Arabic and english meaning) or [Hyper link](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) them to make possible for others to see the verses online.